# For Loop to iterate SQL query in R

Tags: sql, r, for-loop, paste

I would like to iterate this SQL query over the 17 rows in my df. My df and code are below. I think I may need single quotes around dat$ptt_id, because I get a syntax error at the "IN" function. Any ideas how to correctly write this?

df looks like:

```
   ptt_id
1  181787
2  181788
3  184073
4  184098
5  197601
6  197602
7  197603
8  197604
9  197605
10 197606
11 197607
12 197608
13 197609
14 200853
15 200854
16 200851
17 200852
```

#Load data----

```
dat <- read.csv("ptts.csv")
dat2<-list(dat)
```

#Send to database----

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){

  q <- paste("SELECT orgnl_pit, t_name, cap_date, species, sex, mass, cap_lat, cap_lon, sat_appld_id
      FROM main.capev JOIN uid.turtles USING (orgnl_pit)
        WHERE sat_appld_id IN", dat$ptt_id[i],";")
  
  #Get query----
  tags <- dbGetQuery(conn, q)

}

Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "181787"
LINE 3:         WHERE sat_appld_id IN 181787 ;
                                      ^
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Parameter binding.

   ```r
   qmarks <- paste0("(", paste(rep("?", nrow(df)), collapse = ","), ")")
   qmarks
   # [1] "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
   qry <- paste(
     "SELECT orgnl_pit, t_name, cap_date, species, sex, mass, cap_lat, cap_lon, sat_appld_id
      FROM main.capev JOIN uid.turtles USING (orgnl_pit)
      WHERE sat_appld_id IN", qmarks)
   tags <- dbGetQuery(conn, qry, params = df[,1])
   ```
2. Temporary table. This might be more useful when you have a large number of ids to use. (This also works without a temp table if you get the ids from the database anyway, and can use that query in this sub-query.)

   ```r
   dbWriteTable(conn, df, "mytemp")
   qry <- "SELECT orgnl_pit, t_name, cap_date, species, sex, mass, cap_lat, cap_lon, sat_appld_id
           FROM main.capev JOIN uid.turtles USING (orgnl_pit)
           WHERE sat_appld_id IN (select id from mytemp)"
   tags <- dbGetQuery(conn, qry)
   dbExecute(conn, "drop table mytemp")
   ```

   (Name your temp table carefully. DBMSes usually have a nomenclature to ensure the table is automatically cleaned/dropped when you disconnect, often something like `"#mytemp"`. Check with your DBMS or DBA.)

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` operator requires a list. You can think of it as multiple `OR` conditions.

E.g. instead of `WHERE sat_appld_id IN 181787` it should be `WHERE sat_appld_id IN (181787)`

And to that point, instead of a loop you could create a list from your `dat$ptt_id` column for just one sql query such as `WHERE sat_appld_id IN (181787, 181788, 184073, ...)` and do any additional wraggling within your R code instead of making multiple database queries.

Comment: Subsetting in R makes sense, and works. I still am not sure how to modify  WHERE sat_appld_id IN", dat$ptt_id[i],";") to fully query in SQL using a for loop to query only certain data, but I ended up using your suggestion and just bringing the full query into R and then filtering the data I needed via  filter(sat_appld_id %in% tags$ptt_id)